# Adding PHP to jquery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to add php to a jquery function? On ajax success I'm displaying some text in a div using the `.text()` function.

```
success: function(html) {
  msg_each.nextAll('.msg_box:first').text('show some text...').fadeIn(200);
}
```

Via jquery, I would also like to use a Wordpress function:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Post Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
```

How can I add that to the `.text()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. JavaScript runs in the browser. You need to use Ajax (something like [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) to perform an HTTP get on a resource on your server. This will return (probably) HTML or plain text that you can pass into your `.text()` call.

#### Basic skellington

```
success: function (html) {
    $.get('url/to/page.php', function (data) {
        msg_each.nextAll('.msg_box:first').text(data).fadeIn(200);  
    });              
}
```

Since you're already making an Ajax call, however, you might just be able to modify the server-side page you're querying to include the additional HTML (generated by the `comments_popup_link()` call) so you don't have to make an additional XHR.

Comment: Thanks for the code! for `function(data)` do I have to put the name of the function used for `comments_popip_links` in 'data' ?

Comment: @Noob: I don't get what you're asking. Could you clarify? PHP and JavaScript are **totally** separate.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You totally make sense. I meant to ask, can you output the result of a php function in a js function? For example if a function named `test()` echoes `hello world` can I use that in js? Perhaps pass it in a variable